# Weird Compiler behavior (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm trying to add GA library (GALib) to my error-free program, when I add it, the compiler returns strange errors and repeat them so many times... For an example, "syntax error: missing '{' before '<' "  is returned for the first line of the following template code:

```
template<class _Ty>
_Check_return_ inline _Ty _Pow_int(_Ty _Xx, int _Yx) _NOEXCEPT
{
unsigned int _Nx;
if (_Yx >= 0)
    _Nx = static_cast<unsigned int>(_Yx);
else
    _Nx = static_cast<unsigned int>(-_Yx);

for (_Ty _Zx = static_cast<_Ty>(1); ; _Xx *= _Xx)
    {
    if ((_Nx & 1) != 0)
        _Zx *= _Xx;
    if ((_Nx >>= 1) == 0)
        return (_Yx < 0 ? static_cast<_Ty>(1) / _Zx : _Zx);
    }
}
```

The error is in cmath.h
The error is repeated for the same line like for 25 times or so. The same for so many others. (The mentioned error is the first one on the list)
PS. I added the GA files using the following sequence:
1- Project properties>C++>Additional include libraries>select folder
2- Drag-Drop the folder containing the headers and sources to the project solution manager
PPS. All source files are with extension .C not .cpp
How can I solve such situation?

Comment: @Vality This is standard library code.

Comment: @Peet Are they supposed to be C++ or C source files? Probably the library used .C (capital C) meaning C++, but since Windows is case-insensitive it treats .C the same as .c meaning C.

Comment: @immibis I was thinking about that while writing the question actually, so I went back to the documentation of the GA library and found this:

"Set the development environment to use the C++ compiler on .C files (this is the /TP flag in MS Visual C++). Enable RTTI in Visual C++. "

Not sure how to do it though... still searching

Comment: Quite idiotic for a library to use .c as the extension to c++ code.

Comment: @Peet There's an option somewhere in the properties of the source file.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Have to agree about that..

Comment: @immibis Ok, following procedures in this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx

Many errors just vanished (including the mentioned one), now new errors came up I need to deal with -_-

Answer (score 0):

Following procedures in this page: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx Most errors just vanished (including the mentioned one).

The main problem was that the compiler deals with .C files with default option, which I changed to C++ as mentioned in aforementioned page.